# using printf to print a floating number with varying precision

Tags: c, printf

A simple question.
I want to print a floating point number with precision given input from the user, i.e. for `num=2.34567` and `prec=2`, I should print `2.35` as the answer, and for `prec=3`, I should print `2.346`. How can we achieve this? (prec is given input from the user during runtime).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
float num = 2.34567;
int prec = 3;
printf("%.*f", prec, num);
```